# timeupdate event - Fetch POST data in addEventListener

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video

I'm trying to keep track of how long a user is watching a video in my application.

I've landed on just saving a quarter, half and three quarters of the video as they most likely won't watch the whole thing.

My thought is that when the progress variable hits 25, 50 and 75 I fire a fetch POST request to my database. When logging this to console I have multiple timeupdate events, and this will lead to me fetching several times when the if statement triggers. Does anyone have a better solution they might want to share?

https://jsfiddle.net/0L65cfkx/50/ - for those who want to take a look

The Video section:

```
<video src="https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_10mb.mp4" controls>
</video>
```

And my js looks like this

```
const video = document.querySelector('video')

let duration
let progress

video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
  duration = video.duration
}

video.addEventListener('timeupdate', (e) => {
  progress = Math.floor(video.currentTime / duration * 100)
  console.log(progress)
  if(progress == 25) {
  console.log('Seen 25%')
  }
  if(progress == 50) {
  console.log('Seen 25%')
  }
  if(progress == 75) {
  console.log('Seen 25%')
  }
})

video.onended = function() {
console.log(duration)
console.log(progress)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found some code to help out. Credit to [this post](https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/Extensions/HTML-5-Video-Tracking/ta-p/14849)

This solves my problem.

HTML

```
<video src="https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4" controls></video>
```

JS

```
const video = document.querySelector('video')

let not_watched_25 = true;
let not_watched_50 = true;
let not_watched_75 = true;

video.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {

    let currentTime = video.currentTime
  let duration = video.duration
  //double percentages will occur because of calculations. ie. 25.1 % watched and 25.2%watched. 
  //when fixed to decimal places 25 occurs and then 25 occurs again. 
  //boolean value used to call pixel only once.
  let percentage_watched = (currentTime / duration) * 100;

  if ((percentage_watched.toFixed() == 25) && (not_watched_25 == true)) {
    console.log("watched 25%")
    //utag.link({'event_type' : 'video', 'event_action': '25% watched', 'video_milestone': '25%'});
    not_watched_25 = false;
  } else if ((percentage_watched.toFixed() == 50) && (not_watched_50 == true)) {
    console.log("watched 50%")
    //utag.link({'event_type' : 'video', 'event_action': '50% watched', 'video_milestone': '50%'});
    not_watched_50 = false;
  } else if ((percentage_watched.toFixed() == 75) && (not_watched_75 == true)) {
    console.log("watched 75%")
    //utag.link({'event_type' : 'video', 'event_action': '75% watched', 'video_milestone': '75%'});
    not_watched_75 = false;
  }

})
```